# Neo4j: How to speed up a query with multiple merges?

Tags: neo4j

I have a query that creates a node, and relates a large number of nodes to it.

**Example:**

```
CREATE (target :x {index:'a'})
WITH target
MERGE (x1:x {index:'1'}) MERGE (x1)-[:r]->(target)
MERGE (x2:x {index:'2'}) MERGE (x2)-[:r]->(target)
MERGE (x3:x {index:'3'}) MERGE (x3)-[:r]->(target)
...
MERGE (x1000:x {index:'1000'}) MERGE (x1000)-[:r]->(target)
```

I have already set an indexes with `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (x:x) ASSERT x.index IS UNIQUE`. However, this query is currently taking **~45 minutes** to complete.

Is there anything I can do to speed it up? Is adding more CPU power the only option from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you stack `MERGE` or `MATCH` statements like that, you can end up with performance issues (related to result rows). For a case like this, use an iterative loop:

```
CREATE (target :x {index:'a'})
WITH target
FOREACH(i IN RANGE(1, 1000)|
    MERGE (a:x {index: toString(i)})
    MERGE (a) - [:r] -> (target)  )
```

Comment: Thank you Tore. I actually have an array of the indexes (they're unique strings as opposed to being in order from 1-1000). Is it still possible to iterate through them in a similar way?

Comment: Absolutely, just replace `RANGE()` with your list of strings. Even better, pass it in using [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#cypher-parameters) and replace the `x IN RANGE()` with `x IN {list_of_strings}`.

Comment: And remove the string casting (`toString()`) if the list already contains strings.